# a problem related with Galois theory

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

suppose $E/F$ is finite Galois extension, $M$ is intermediate field ,i.e $F \subset M \subset E$
Is the identity $(*)$ true?$$Inv(\mathop\bigcap \limits_{\sigma \in Gal(E/F)}(\sigma \cdot Gal(E/M) \cdot\sigma^{-1}))=\mathop\bigcap \limits_{\sigma \in Gal(E/F)} Inv (\sigma \cdot Gal(E/M) \cdot\sigma^{-1})$$

Comment: What is "$Inv$"?

Comment: Invariant field

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't correct.  The correspondence between intermediate fields and subgroups of $Gal(E/F)$ *reverses* the direction of inclusions: if you have a larger subgroup, then its fixed field is smaller (since the more group elements you have, the harder it is for a field element to be fixed by all of them).  This means that the fixed field of an intersection of subgroups is not the intersection of their fixed fields, but rather the subfield generated by the *union* of their fixed fields.

Comment: Thanks, could you help to show how to prove the LHS  equals to subfield generated by the union of their fixed fields?